# How to insert PowerShell variables into a string block

Tags: powershell

Quick question, i'm trying to insert a variable into a string json body block like below, but when i perform a rest api call by passing the json body into the invoke-webrequest function, the variable is actually not getting inserted. In the alert software i'm using i just see the message as 'The following host $($scrapperHost) is not running!!'

```
 #variable
    $myHost = $Env:Computername
    #variable prints the correct hostname
    #string json body
    $jsonBody = @'
    {
        "message": "The following host $($myHost) is not running!!"}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can insert variables into strings / [Here Strings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/).

For your specific example, instead of using `@' '@` you can use `@" "@`, and you can insert the variable without the `$` at the beginning:

```
#variable
$myHost = $Env:Computername
#variable prints the correct hostname
#string json body
$jsonBody = @"
{
    "message": "The following host ${myHost} is not running!!"}
}
"@
```

This would also work fine, always using `@" "@`:

`"message": "The following host $myHost is not running!!"`

Or:

```
# This is very useful when you want to insert a property of your variable
"message": "The following host $($myHost) is not running!!"`
```

Another example:

```
$jsonBody = @'
{{
    "message": "The following host {0} is not running!!"
}}
'@ -f $myHost
```

Notice I'm using double `{{ }}` because you need to escape, basically you're telling Powershell you want a literal curly brace instead of using the curly brace as a special character.

There are a lot more examples you can use to insert variables into strings, check out this post by Kevin Marquette: https://powershellexplained.com/2017-01-13-powershell-variable-substitution-in-strings/

Comment: You're an absolute legend. Thanks allot :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help @aravind1994